# error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

Tags: python, image, opencv

I know that there are already other questions regarding the argument, but all i understood is that i need to check the dimension of the images. Here i printed those and they're the same. I'm stuck i really don't know how to proceed.

Here is the full code.

"mascheraT1" and "mascheraT2" are 2 images. What i wanted to do is simply find the differences between these two images (it's "parziale" and then "definitiva") and highlight those on the original image which is maschera1 (and it should be "evidenziato", but it doesn't work). "ridotta1" and "definitiva" have both 'uint8' as dtype.

```
from pathlib import Path
import cv2 as cv
from cv2 import waitKey
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def rescale(immagine, moltiplicatore):
    new_high = int(immagine.shape[0] * moltiplicatore)
    new_width = int(immagine.shape[1] * moltiplicatore)
    return cv.resize(immagine, (new_width, new_high), interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)


mascheraT1 = cv.imread("Casi possibili (maschere)\Movimento\imm9.png")
mascheraT2 = cv.imread("Casi possibili (maschere)\Movimento\Oggetto tolto.png")

ridotta1 = rescale(mascheraT1, 0.5)
ridotta2 = rescale(mascheraT2, 0.5)

cv.imshow('Machera al tempo T1', ridotta1)
cv.imshow("Maschera al tempo T2", ridotta2)

#blank = np.zeros((int(1920 * 0.5), int(1080 * 0.5)), dtype='uint8')
parziale = cv.subtract(ridotta1, ridotta2)
cv.imshow("Sottrazione parziale", parziale)

lower = np.array([30,20,20])
upper = np.array([230,200,200])
maschera = cv.inRange(parziale, lower, upper)
res = cv.bitwise_and(parziale, parziale, mask=maschera)
#cv.imshow('Pulizia',res)

definitiva = cv.subtract(parziale, res)
gray_version = cv.cvtColor(definitiva, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #serve per countNonZero
#cv.imshow("Grigia", gray_version)
if cv.countNonZero(gray_version) == 0:
    print("Image is black")
else:
    print("Colored image")

#definitiva = cv.resize(definitiva, (960, 540))
#Show the dimension of the working images
height1, width1, channel1 = ridotta1.shape
print((height1, width1, channel1))
height2, width2, channel2 = definitiva.shape
print((height2, width2, channel2))

evidenziato = cv.bitwise_and(ridotta1, ridotta1, mask=definitiva)
cv.imshow("Sovrapposizione", evidenziato)


cv.imshow("Definitiva", definitiva)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Here is the terminal:

```
Colored image
(540, 960, 3)
(540, 960, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Università\Terzo anno\Laurea\Tirocinio\Progetto\Background 
subtraction.py", line 49, in <module>
evidenziato = cv.bitwise_and(ridotta1, ridotta1, mask=definitiva)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:230: error: (-215:Assertion 
failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in 
function 'cv::binary_op'
```

Here is the part that causes the error:

```
evidenziato = cv.bitwise_and(ridotta1, ridotta1, mask=definitiva)
```

Comment: mascheraT1 or mascheraT2 is None, right? not only the shapes need to be right, the dtypes must be right too! you should provide all this information.

Comment: No, mascheraT1 and mascheraT2 are 2 images. You're right, i knew i was going to forget something. This is my absolute first post on the site, and like coding, it's never right the first time ahaha! I'm adding everything you said, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the mask you apply on the bitwise operator needs to be black and white, mine wasn't.